# Postfix header_checks general understanding but further questions

Tags: postfix-mta

I am not sure if I completely understannd what header_checks can do for me. I am using postfix with virtual_alias_tables for realizing a simple mailing-list. Now I want every member of the list reply to that list specific address and not to the other members address.

I give you an example:

- member -> writes mail to list
- all other members recieve this mail
- any member who replies to this mail has the lists address predefined
- ... and so on

So far so good. I've setup a simple header_check thats working for the first reply.

```
/^To: name_of_list@domain.de/ PREPEND name_of_list@domain.de
```

But as the second reply occurs this header_check is not working at all, and the reply goes to the members adress.

Question: what is the difference between smtp_header_checks and header_checks? How to determine if a header is manipulated during reception or during delivery? And how can I ensure that every mail that was initally written into this mailing-list will be replied to itself?

Thanks for your help.